# How to find parameter types of Action (using reflection)?

Tags: .net, vb.net, reflection, parameters, action

I have a method that takes an array of actions as parameter. The actions in this array should always require 1 parameter, *but the parameter type can differ*.

The method should check what type of parameter an action requires before calling it. If it requires a `String`, the parameter will be `"text"`. If it requires an `Integer`, The parameter will be `123`.

This is what I've tried:

```
Sub MethodA(ParamArray actions() As Action(Of Object))
  For Each action() As Action(Of Object) In actions
    If action.Method.GetParameters()(0).ParameterType = GetType(String) Then
      action("text")
    ElseIf action.Method.GetParameters()(0).ParameterType = GetType(Integer) Then
      action(123)
    ElseIf ...
      ' You get the point.
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

However, `action.Method.GetParameters()(0).ParameterType` is always `Object`, probably because the parameter array of `MethodA` only takes `Action(Of Object)`.

Since my code does not work, what else can I try? How can I find what type the action **really** requires?

**Note**: I could use `Try ... Catch`, but I would like to determine what parameter type is required *without* calling the method.

**Edit**: I've found behaviour of `Action(Of T)` and `AddressOf` that I don't understand, and it's probably related to my question. See the following piece of code:

```
Sub MyStringMethod(s As String)
  ' Do something
End Sub

MethodA(AddressOf MyStringMethod) ' Compiles
Dim stringAction As Action(Of String) = AddressOf MyStringMethod
MethodA(stringAction) 'Does not compile
```

What makes the difference here? Does `AddressOf` generate an `Action(Of Object)`?

Comment: What else can you try? Going back to the drawing board and examining if this is really the best way to solve whatever problem it is that you're trying to solve.

Comment: @Jamiec: I know I'm writing unclean code, but unfortunately I'm working with a poorly designed library. What I explained above seems like the only possibility of solving my problem.

Comment: @L.B: Yes, but that does not solve my problem. If I don't check the parameter type and call `Invoke`, I will get an exeption when I use a wrong parameter type, which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: What's wrong with getting an exception?  Just catch it and then in the catch, just do whatever it was you were going to do if the type didn't match one of the ones you were checking for.

Comment: @RuudLenders One more try. `Convert.ChangeType`

Comment: @StevenDoggart: There's nothing wrong with getting an exception, but what if I want to know if the parameters types match *without* calling the method? I'll add some more information above to be clear.

Comment: For what it's worth, in VS2005, `MethodA(AddressOf MyStringMethod)` doesn't compile either.

Comment: @StevenDoggart: well, this time I'm 100% sure that it does compile in VS2010. Double checked it ;)

Comment: Can you ask for an array of the base `Delegate` type instead of the generic `Action(Of Object)` type?  If so, I think that may work for you.  For instance, `Sub MethodA(ParamArray actions() As [Delegate])`

Comment: @StevenDoggart: That works, thanks! If you could make an answer out of that, I will accept it :)

Comment: Yay!  For a few minutes there I thought hope might be lost...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that there is no way to set an `Action(Of Object)` variable to an `Action(Of String)` or `Action(Of Integer)` object, for instance:

```
Dim actions(2) As Action(Of Object)
'The following lines will not compile
actions(0) = New Action(Of String)(AddressOf MyStringMethod)
actions(0) = New Action(Of Integer)(AddressOf MyIntegerMethod)
```

So the problem is not where you are checking the type.  The problem is that you could never pass any other type into the method in the first place, so how could the method possibly know?

Either you need to pass the type in with each action by creating a wrapper class, for instance:

```
Public Class MyAction
    Public Sub New(ByVal action As Action(Of Object), ByVal parameterType As Type)
        _action = action
        _type = Type
    End Sub

    Public ReadOnly Property Action() As Action(Of Object)
        Get
            Return _action
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _action As Action(Of Object)

    Public ReadOnly Property Type() As Type
        Get
            Return _type
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _type As Type
End Class
```

Or, if all the items in the array take the same parameter, then you could ask for the type as a parameter to your method, for instance:

```
Sub MethodA(ParamArray actions() As Action(Of Object), parameterType As Type)
    '...
End Sub
```

**UPDATE**

Based on subsequent conversation, what you need to do is to just use the base `Delegate` type instead of the `Action(Of Object)` type.  For instance:

```
Sub MethodA(ParamArray actions() As [Delegate])
    '...
End Sub
```

However, by doing so, you're allowing delegates with other types of signatures to be passed in, for instance, it would allow a `Function` instead of a `Sub`, or a method with zero parameters, or too many parameters, instead of exactly one.  So, you may need to do some extra checking inside to make sure the signature of the delegate is what you are expecting.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong, but those lines compile just fine.

Comment: @RuudLenders Interesting... I'm testing it in VS2005, which does not allow that.  It says "Value of type Action(Of String) cannot be converted to Action(Of Object)."  I wonder if that's something that was made more flexible in a more recent version of VB, or if it's allowed when `Option Infer On`.

Comment: Oops, my bad. Those lines won't compile. Strange, why can't you assign `Action(Of String)` to `Action(Of Object)`, while you can pass it as parameter to `MethodA`, which takes `Action(Of Object)`?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  You shouldn't be able to pass it to `MethodA` either.  Can you give an example?

Comment: See the edit I've made. It demonstrates how you can't assign different types of actions to each other directly, while you assign them when using `AddressOf`.